# How to fill shape outside on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I work with canvas and draw closed line with the mouse, than fill the inner area by some color(green for example). How do I fill the outer area, not the inner.
Here is chunk of code I use:

```
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
      draw = false;
});
```

Here is an example that I want to implement

https://jsfiddle.net/tonycaso/drxpb8vy/24/

But it use fabricjs library, I need to do it by native canvas and js.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `globalCompositeOperation`. It sets the type of compositing operation to apply when drawing new shapes. You might want to read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation).

In your case, you can first fill the entire canvas with a color (say, green). Then let the mouse draw the shape. When the shape is drawn, fill it using the global composite operation `destination-out`. It will cut the shape out from the background resulting in the outer area remaining filled.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.canvas.width = 300;
context.canvas.height = 300;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
  context.closePath();

  // Fill a rect on the entire canvas with the desired color
  context.fillStyle = "green";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // Cut out the drawn shape
  context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  context.fill();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  cursor: crosshair;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically that is really hard. You would need to write a custom function checking every pixel. What we can do to make it easier is

```
background (what color you want to fill)
fill(the original Background color)
//drawYourShape
```